# How can I implement a checkbox label with additional content on hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, checkbox

[Kayak](https://www.kayak.com/flights/MSY,nearby-MSN,nearby/2016-09-28/2016-09-29) uses a checkbox menu with an "only" option in the label that displays on `:hover`.  How can this be implemented, with JS and/or CSS?

[image]

Comment: Fixed the question so it's on-topic.  Voted to re-open.  I recommend others do the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the Chrome Inspector, it is easy to see how Kayak implemented this:

html:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="right">
    <a class="only">only</a>
    <a class="price">$500</a>
  </div>
  <span>
    ...checkbox ...1 stop
  </span>
</div>
```

css:

```
.right {
  float: right;
}
.only {
  display: none;
}
.row:hover .only {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I am using chrome and `.price` goes to a new line when `.row:hover` occurs. Also, does this approach allow to align the 3 columns vertically? The pic in the example has 3-digits prices, but if I had 4-5 digits prices the `only` button would be misaligned.

Comment: Are you using a grid layout like bootstrap, foundation, materialize, etc? Then each row will have a 50% column for the checkbox and name, 25% column for "only", and 25% column for price. The "only" column will contain a `<a>` or `<span>` which shows on hover. My answer is a proof-of-concept, you can figure out the rest.

Comment: None of them right now but thank you for suggesting.

Comment: To fix the `.price` moving to the next line, change `display: block` to `display: inline`. Although you'll ideally be using a block element with a percentage width (which is what bootstrap et al does).